# Saving an item through factory casts an error with AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using Firebase and AngularJS bundled up together and as I'm in the learningprocess of both, I guess. I'm having some trouble saving an item through a factory with Angular.

This is my script

```
var app = angular.module('LinkApp', ['firebase']);

    app.constant('FirebaseLinks', 'https://[hidden].firebaseio.com/links')

    app.controller('LinkCtrl', ['$scope', 'LinksFactory',
        function($scope, LinksFactory) {
            // get links
            $scope.links = LinksFactory.getItems();

            // update link
            $scope.updateLink = function(link) {
                LinksFactory.updateItem(link);
            };
        }
    ]);

    app.factory('LinksFactory', ['$firebase', 'FirebaseLinks',
        function($firebase, FirebaseLinks) {
            var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseLinks);
            var items = $firebase(ref);

            return {
                getItems: function() {
                    return items.$asArray();
                },

                updateItem: function(item) {
                    items.$save(item);
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

This is my html

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links | orderBy: link.number">
    <input type="number" ng-model="link.number" ng-blur="updateLink(link)">
    {{ link.name }}: <a href="{{ link.url }}" target="_blank">{{ link.url }}</a>
</div>
```

I'm using my blur function (updateLink) to pass my item into my factory, but from there I get this error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

If I pass my item to my function and save my collection from there width $scope.links.$save(link), it is successfull.

How can this be?

Thanks in regards. Say if you need further details.

Comment: Why not just `return $firebase(ref).$asArray()`? Why this awkward wrapper that just does the same thing that AngularFire already accomplishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of work I figured it out.

I had to return my factory functions and I had to call my variable 'items' with an $asArray() at the end and remove the $asArray() from my getItems function.

But now it works :)